# How to split big list item in different items

Tags: python, list, dataframe, split, delimiter

I have a list of elements, but these element should be seperated into more elements by the ,-delimiter.

```
[[{'col1': '81627', 'picture_date': '2018-03-26'},
  {'col1': '82034', 'picture_date': '2018-03-28'},
  {'col1': '81625', 'picture_date': '2018-03-26'},
  {'col1': '81626', 'picture_date': '2018-03-26'}]]
```

This is one list item list[1] but it should be divided into 4 list items. What is an efficient way to do that?

Comment: Are you asking how to turn this into a structure like so [{}, {}, {}, {}]?

Comment: yes a list of multiple element instead of a list of this one big item

Comment: What is the desired output ?

Comment: A list of 4 items [{},{},{},{}] so I would afterwards be able to transform it into a dataframe of 4 rows and two columns 'col1' and 'picture_date'

Comment: Does `pd.DataFrame([l for d in data for l in d])` answer the question ?

Comment: Yes it does! it combines both steps, thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to flatten the list:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([l for d in data for l in d])
```

*output*:

```
#     col1 picture_date
# 0  81627   2018-03-26
# 1  82034   2018-03-28
# 2  81625   2018-03-26
# 3  81626   2018-03-26
```

---

**Edit**

To be able to perform some computations with the data, you need to convert the column with their appropriate *type*. You can see the `types` using [`dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html)

```
print(df.dtypes)
# col1            object
# picture_date    object
# dtype: object
```

- To convert data to **numeric**, a solution is to use [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html).
- To convert data to **time object**, a solution is to used [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

```
df["col1"] = pd.to_numeric(df["col1"])
df["picture_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["picture_date"])
print(df.dtypes)
# col1                     int64
# picture_date    datetime64[ns]
# dtype: object
```

Comment: This is a very efficient way to convert it into a DataFrame but for some reason I'm not able to do any calculations with the column rows

Comment: This is because the columns types are string, see to update to tackle this problem.

Answer (score 0):

i think this will work for you

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> alist= [[{'col1': '81627', 'picture_date': '2018-03-26'},
...   {'col1': '82034', 'picture_date': '2018-03-28'},
...   {'col1': '81625', 'picture_date': '2018-03-26'},
...   {'col1': '81626', 'picture_date': '2018-03-26'}]]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(alist[0])
>>> df
    col1 picture_date
0  81627   2018-03-26
1  82034   2018-03-28
2  81625   2018-03-26
3  81626   2018-03-26
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that, using a list comprehension (for those of us who **don't know pandas** yet):

```py
your_list = [[
    {'col1': '81627', 'picture_date': '2018-03-26'},
    {'col1': '82034', 'picture_date': '2018-03-28'},
    {'col1': '81625', 'picture_date': '2018-03-26'},
    {'col1': '81626', 'picture_date': '2018-03-26'},
    ]]

what_you_want = [item for sub_list in your_list for item in sub_list]
print(what_you_want)
```

Output:

```
[{'col1': '81627', 'picture_date': '2018-03-26'}, {'col1': '82034', 'picture_date': '2018-03-28'}, {'col1': '81625', 'picture_date': '2018-03-26'}, {'col1': '81626', 'picture_date': '2018-03-26'}]
```